# Remove the value from the linked list

Tags: python, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

**Given the head of a linked list and an integer val, remove all the nodes of the linked list that has Node.val == val, and return the new head.**

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head: Optional[ListNode], val: int) -> Optional[ListNode]:
      #Checking if head is empty
        if (head == None):
            return head
        
        prev = head
        curr = head
        while curr:
            if curr.val == val:
                if curr == prev:
                    head = head.next
                    prev = prev.next
                   
                else:
                    prev.next = curr.next
            else:
            
                if curr != prev:
                    prev = prev.next
            curr = curr.next
            return head`
    ``
```

Comment: The code you attached seems to do exactly what you want (did not read too carefully but the general idea was there). What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that your final `return head` is part of the `while` loop, so the loop will only iterate once. Fix this by moving that statement out of the loop (less indent).

With that fix, it will work.

### Other remarks

- It is a bit awkward that you have initialised `prev` as `head`. This means you need to keep it updated when the `head` node is removed from the list. I would suggest to initialise `prev` as `None`.
- There is no need to have the case of the empty list treated separately. The loop will not iterate in that case, so you'll get the expected result without that `if` statement at the start of the function.
- In the outer `else` block there is no need for an `if` when you just do `prev = curr`.

### Code

```
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head, val):
        prev = None  # Initialise like this
        curr = head
        while curr:
            if curr.val == val:
                if not prev:
                    head = curr.next
                else:
                    prev.next = curr.next
            else:
                prev = curr
            curr = curr.next
        return head  # Not part of the loop
```

Another idea is to first deal with removals *after* the head node. And at the end check if the first node must be kept. Then the code can become:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head, val):
        curr = head
        while curr.next:
            if curr.next.val == val:
                curr.next = curr.next.next
            else:
                curr = curr.next
        return head.next if head and head.val == val else head
```

With recursion it could look like this:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head, val):
        if not head:
            return head
        head.next = self.removeElements(head.next, val)
        return head.next if head.val == val else head
```